# Passing useState data from one functional component to another

Tags: reactjs

I have two function components with useState in two different files in my project. I want to display the url on my FaceRecognition component if I set fetchSuccess to true.

```
const ImageLinkForm = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [fetchSuccess, setFetchSuccess] = useState(false);
  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    // I get the url and fetchSuccess is true
  };
  return (
    <div>
     // I return a form that allowed me to make the fetch call
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageLinkForm;


const FaceRecognition = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* if fetchSuccess */}
      <img src=url />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FaceRecognition;
```

Comment: The standard react approach to share data is to [lift the state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example), then pass it down to the components that need it.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how these components are hierarchically related but one easy-ish option is to use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```jsx
// context/image.js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ImageContext = createContext({ fetchSuccess: false });

export const ImageContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [fetchSuccess, setFetchSuccess] = useState(false);

  const setSuccessful = () => {
    setFetchSuccess(true);
  };

  return (
    <ImageContext.Provider value={{ fetchSuccess, setSuccessful }}>
      {children}
    </ImageContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Your components can then use the context to read the value...

```jsx
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ImageContext } from "path/to/context/image";

const FaceRecognition = () => {
  const { fetchSuccess } = useContext(ImageContext);

  return <div>{fetchSuccess && <img src="url" />}</div>;
};
```

and write the value...

```jsx
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { ImageContext } from "path/to/context/image";

const ImageLinkForm = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const { setSuccessful } = useContext(ImageContext);

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    // I get the url and fetchSuccess is true
    setSuccessful();
  };
  return (
    <div>{/* I return a form that allowed me to make the fetch call */}</div>
  );
};
```

The only thing you need to do is wrap both these components somewhere in the hierarchy with the provider

```jsx
import { ImageContextProvider } from "path/to/context/image";

const SomeParent = () => (
  <ImageContextProvider>
    <ImageLinkForm />
    <FaceRecognition />
  </ImageContextProvider>
);
```