# is there any way for me to change the state of a useState from one file to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

## React.js

i want to change the `let [show, setshow] = React.useState(true)` from (false) to (true) on the header file

> Search.jsx

```
function Search() {

    let [show, setshow] = React.useState(true)

    return (
        show ?         <>
        <div id='screen' className='screen'>
        <div className="inputContainer">
        
        <div className="input">
        <input id='inputScreen' type="text" placeholder='search the index...'/>
        <button onClick={() => setshow(false)} id='pesquisar' className="btnSearch"><FontAwesomeIcon id='lupa' icon={faMagnifyingGlass}/></button>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div className="message">
        <h3 className='text-center'>does not work...yet <br /> (just let me further study about await) </h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        </> : null
    );
}
```

> Search.jsx

```
function Header() {

    return (
        <>
        
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/40efce30ee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <header className='header'>

        <button onClick={/*HERE IS WHERE I WANNA CHANGE THE OTHER FILE STATE*//} id='logo' className='text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-{flow} h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500'>W</button>
        <button className='button'>DTN<span className='text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-{flow} h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500'>W</span></button>
        <button id='logoRight'><FontAwesomeIcon id='lupa' icon={faMagnifyingGlass}/></button>

        
        </header>
        </>
    );
}
```

i want to further explain that im a react beginner and i would highly appreciate any help

i tried on using *props* but i could not get the result i wanted to

Comment: _Redux_ is the typical approach.

Comment: This sounds very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74118748/283366)